# How to save/load Properties from/to a View/Singleton-Class

Tags: c#, wpf, view, singleton, viewmodel

Heyo guys,

i have now a little problem in my program which bothers me more than it should.

This over here is the Singleton-class i use in my program.

```
public class Resources
{
    private static Resources _instance;

    public static Resources Instance
    {
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new Resources()); }
    }

    #region Properties

    public Candidate Candidate { get; set; }
    public Enterprise Enterprise { get; set; }
    public WikomContact WikomContact { get; set; }
    public AMSContact AMSContact { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

I use these Candidate/Enterprise/...-Objects as ItemSources for my ComboBoxes, this works quite well.
To use these objects in other viewmodels too I want to save them to a Singleton-class, from there i wanted to load them in all the other viewmodels.

```
public _0InfoTalkViewModel()
{
    _context = new WikomContext();
    RefreshViewCommand = new RelayCommand(RefreshView);
    PrintViewCommand = new RelayCommand(PrintView);
    SaveViewCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveView);
    EnterpriseIsEnabled = false;
    WikomContactIsEnabled = true;

    Candidate = Resources.Instance.Candidate;
    Enterprise = Resources.Instance.Enterprise;
    WikomContact = Resources.Instance.WikomContact;
}
```

And here is for example one of the comboboxes I use in my program.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Enterprise" Margin="3" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EnterpriseList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Enterprise, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                              IsEditable="True"
                              IsEnabled="{Binding EnterpriseIsEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              Margin="3" Grid.Column="1">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RefreshViewCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

The SaveView-method looks like this

```
public void SaveView()
{
    Resources.Instance.Candidate = Candidate;
    Resources.Instance.Enterprise = Enterprise;
    Resources.Instance.WikomContact = WikomContact;
}
```

The RefreshView-method gets also triggered when the form gets loaded.
The problem is, the comboboxes get the right input from the database, but if i select one of them, then change the view and load it again, the SelectedValue is not the one I put in before ...

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ? Or can anyone tell me why my "idea/method" doesnt work ?

Sorry for bad english, i usually speak german! ;)

Comment: I don't understand: you're never using the singleton instance of `Resources`, just its static properties. Why not just make `Resources` static?

Comment: Oh yeah, I see ... I am not that familiar with singletons, thats why I am here ;) I changed it now to the instance of a singleton, but it still won't work ... Any more ideas ?

Comment: You do not need `public static Resource Instance` at all. Declare `Resource` to be a static class and access properties as you were: `Resource.Candidate`, for example.

Comment: Your code won't compile as written since `Candidate` is a class name, not a value of type `Candidate` (at `Resources.Instance.Candidate = Candidate`). Please edit your post once you have updated your code.

Comment: My properties are called "Candidate" too! ;) Is this bad ? Could this be my mistake ? Wait I try to rename them! :o //edit: Tried to rename my properties, doesnt work as well -> Thats not my mistake ... Any more ideas ? :(
@Kjata30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snaylor;

Your properties should not be static, they should be instance properties:

```
public Candidate Candidate { get; set; }
public Enterprise Enterprise { get; set; }
public WikomContact WikomContact { get; set; }
public AMSContact AMSContact { get; set; }
```

When you reference your singleton, Resources it should be a reference to the Instance:

```
Candidate = Resources.Instance.Candidate;
Resources.Instance.Candidate = Candidate;
```

Comment: Ahh okay good to know, yeah I am not so familiar with singletons ... I changed it now to the instance, but it still doesnt work ... Any more ideas ? :o @Ibrahim Malluf

Comment: Did you change your properties from static to instance like I showed you in the code?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, havent seen your post, yeah I did so, still won't work ...

Comment: I reread your post here, and if I now understand you correctly you are expecting your singleton class to survive from request to request. That is not going to happen since state is not saved.  You need a way to persist state between requests.

Comment: Yeah I solved this problem already yesterday, I had an issue with the event which loads the objects from the singleton-class in my viewmodel.
I marked your answer as "accepted" already! Thanks for the help! :)